# collision without contact listener

Tags: objective-c

i went through Raywenderlich game like fruitninja and implemented how to cut the object into two pieces using custom shapes of polygon. i enhanced my game by setting other non breakable objects. while creating bodies , if i set user data the objects are not creating. without setting user data i can able to create the objects. but i need to write contact listeners for two non breakable objects. but without setting user data im not able to write listeners,if i set user data i cannot able to slice the objects.  can anyone help to detect collisions without contact listeners and to destroy the body